# Return latest record from 1 to Many Relationship table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have two tables named Visit and VisitMovement that are in a 1-to-many relationship, i.e. 1 Visit can have many VisitMovement rows. I've taken out all the detail fields but these are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit]
(
    [VisitID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VisitMovement](
    [VisitMovementID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VisitID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

A lot of the time I need to return the Visit and the details from the latest VisitMovement row.

Currently what I do is have these two views, but it is getting slower as time goes by.

For example if I do select * from vwGetVisit where VisitID = 1245 it takes a few seconds to return, and the cost is mostly over on the vwLatestVisitMovement object.

What would a better way be to achieve this?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwGetVisit] as
        SELECT 
                V.*
                VM.*
            FROM 
                Visit V
            INNER JOIN VisitMovement VM ON
                V.VisitID = VM.VisitID
            INNER JOIN vwLatestVisitMovement LVM on
                VM.VisitMovementID = LVM.VisitMovementID
           ....many other joins including left joins....

CREATE View [dbo].[vwLatestVisitMovement] 
AS
    SELECT
        VisitID,
        max(VisitMovementID) as VisitMovementID
    FROM
        dbo.VisitMovement
    GROUP BY
        VisitID
```

Comment: A _single_ index on table `VisitMovement` on columns `VisitId` ascending, `VisitMovementId` _descending_ should help. That allows the inner join to find a matching row quickly, and the first row will be the most recent. (NB: This assumes that `VisitMovementId` provides a meaningful order. If there is another column you omitted, e.g. `MovementDate`, then substitute that for the descending index column.)

Comment: Thanks HABO, that did make a difference. Before it was Table 'VisitMovement'. Scan count 2, logical reads 1038, now its Table 'VisitMovement'. Scan count 2, logical reads 526.

Comment: That is not valid.  You join on LVM.VisitMovementID and ignore VisitID.

Comment: What would you suggest @Paparazzi?

Comment: Do I have to spell it out?  Don't ignore VisitID. Returning multiple rows was not a clue something was wrong?

Comment: @Paparazzi - it isn't returning multiple rows currently, that's not the problem. If I join on VisitID, that's when I get the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join visitMovement with vwLatestVisitMovement on VisitMovementID. It souds strange to me... vwLatestVisitMovement .VisitMovementId is calculated using MAX and cost a lot join with this field.  I think could be more naturally  join vwLatestVisitMovement with Visit on VisitID, you should get same result but a better query plan.

If you need alla data from VisitMOvement you can use CROSS APPLY or ROW_NUMBER() OVER.

Usually I prefer ROW_NUMBER() OVER.

Try this and see if performance are better:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwGetVisit] as
        SELECT 
                V.*
                , LVM.*
            FROM 
                Visit V
            INNER JOIN vwLatestVisitMovement LVM on
                V.VisitID = LVM.VisitID                
           ....many other joins including left joins....

CREATE View [dbo].[vwLatestVisitMovement] 
AS
    WITH LVM AS (
        -- replace * with fields!
        SELECT VM.*
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VM.VisitID ORDER BY VM.VisitMovementID DESC) AS CheckLastId
        FROM dbo.VisitMovement AS VM
    )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        LVM
    WHERE CheckLastId = 1
GO
```

With cross appply:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwGetVisit] as
        SELECT 
                V.*
                , LVM.*
            FROM 
                Visit V
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) LM.* FROM dbo.VisitMovement AS LM WHERE LM.VisitID = V.VisitID ORDER BY LM.VisitMovementID DESC ) AS LVM
           ....many other joins including left joins....
```

Comment: Thanks Ezin. That's ideal and heaps faster, but the problem with joining both vwLatestVisitMovement and VisitMovement on the VisitID is that it brings back all rows, not just the latest one. Any ideas?

Comment: ok now I understand, sorry. I've changed my answer, hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Ezin, that improves it out of sight. There's an odd problem related to it though that I'll post another question for.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes on `VisitID` should help solve your problem:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_vwGetVisit_VisitID 
     ON [vwGetVisit] (VisitID);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_vwLatestVisit_VisitID 
     ON [vwLastestVisitMovement] (VisitID);
```

Views aren't known for great performance however, you may be better off repeating the query as needed if you continue to have performance issues.

Comment: @Philip On the table or the view?

Comment: Sorry, not on the view. It isn't compatible though - Cannot create index on view "vwGetVisit" because it uses a LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL OUTER join, and no OUTER joins are allowed in indexed views. Consider using an INNER join instead.
I cut off a whole heap of joins from the view sorry, as I didn't think it was relevant. I apologise for that.